# Simulate soundcard to test audio program

Tags: c, testing, audio, portaudio

I am currently developing an audio application using Portaudio.
To test it, I would like to control the input and thus check the output of my application. However, I would love to achieve this only internally.

Do you know of any software able to emulate a soundcard, whose output would be the input of my Portaudio program and whose input would be the output of my Portaudio program?

Comment: You mean a software that would create sample sounds of some specified frequency, amplitude, phase, shape? Did you try to search on the internet?

Comment: Actually, I mean one software which would be able to send audio to Portaudio and to get this audio back. I can not use an external soundcard as I do not have enough I/Os. I searched on the Internet and found Soundflower but I don't think it really fits my expectations.

Comment: So, how do you feed data to Portaudio? You call some function, or send data to a socket?

Comment: For now, I use my internal soundcard but I have to increase the number of channels in order to having a 5.1 input, which I can not have physically. Furthermore, working with my internal soundcard does not allow me to properly control input and output signals. I don't know if my problem makes sense, maybe the solution is really easy but I didn't find it yet.

Comment: Ok, but how do you feed audio to PortAudio? Via function? Via socket? Or you can only feed data to PortAudio by a soundcard?

Comment: By a soundcard. When initializing Portaudio, it gets the list of the available audio devices and connect to the one we want to process and consume audio data. What I would like is to have a virtual audio device which would be an interface between Portaudio and another audio program on my computer (Audacity for example) to provide custom audio to my program, some kind of redirection/pipe but for audio

Comment: Well, did you look for any program in the search engine? "sound card emulator" gives a lot of results

Comment: I checked both here and on Google but I can't find some simple software with basic I/O functionalities. I want something like JACK but easier to set up